# SSRS report showing blank row under hidden group row

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I am building a report that breaks down overdue actions for my company's task management software.

I have created a row group that allows users to toggle visibility of different action codes to drill down into specific tasks, however, when the report is run, there is a blank row between each of the grouped fields.

Here is what the report looks like within 'Design' mode in Visual Studio:
[image: Report in design mode]

The bottom two rows are the ones that are to be hidden under the 'Expr' row:
[image: Row visibility settings]

However, when I run the report, it appears with a blank row in between each toggle row:
[image: Report in preview mode]

This blank row seems to disappear once the row group is toggled open.
How can I get rid of this blank row?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: It sounds like you're using the Group visibility instead of the ROW visibility. The group is hidden but the line is still there. Right-click on the Detail lines (3 lines in lower left of 1st pic) on the left of the table's design view and use the Visibility in the Row Properties (and remove the Group visibility).

Comment: @HannoverFist thanks - that was it. Sorry to bother you with such trivial things!